# My code is setting the objects to the wrong parent, how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So I am currently programming for a school thesis and the current plan for my code to work, or atleast I think it should, was to set the object as a child of the assigned parent under the condition of a drag and drop using collision as a sensor using a if condition. However, when I run the game, the objects I want to set as a child are going to the wrong parents. This is basically what happens.

[image: Image 1]

So the images under the grid as seen in the hierarchy are what I want to be assigned as children by another parent.

[image: Image 2]

And the LetterSLot in the hiearchy are what i want to assign as Parents of the Images in run time.

When I run the game, this is basically what happens:
[image: Image 3]

As you can see, it seems to me that the Images game objects are somehow assigning themselves as children of the scene itself, if I'm understanding this right.

Here is the code i used for this logic:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;

public class ParentSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsOnSlot = false;
    [SerializeField] GameObject[] LetterInputTile;
    
    [SerializeField] GameObject letterInputTileParent;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        letterInputTileParent = new GameObject("LetterInputTileParent");
        LetterInputTile = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MLetterTile");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        foreach (GameObject obj in LetterInputTile)
        {
            if (IsOnSlot)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < LetterInputTile.Length; i++)
                {
                    LetterInputTile[i].transform.SetParent(letterInputTileParent.transform);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < LetterInputTile.Length; i++)
                {
                    LetterInputTile[i].transform.SetParent(null);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
        {
            IsOnSlot = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
        {
            IsOnSlot = false;
        }
    }
}
```

IS my logic somehow wrong somewhere? or did I set something in the inspector wrong?
Image of inspector:
[image: Image 4]

Its the Parent Setter component in the inspector?

How do I fix this?

Update:
The code seems to be working as intended according to the inspector as seen in the image.
[image: Image 5]

But the problem still seems to persist in a way that the hierarchy doesnt seem to think so and still assigns itself as the parent of the objects.

How do i fix this?

Comment: If you want "LetterSLot" to be the parent, I think this word should appear in the code, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing

```
 LetterInputTile[i].transform.SetParent(null);
```

which will set your objects to the scene root level. But they seem to be `UI.Image` components which have to be nested under a `Canvas` in order to be rendered.

Also your newly created object `LetterInputTileParent` is not nested under the `Canvas` but on scene root level.

=> You most probably would rather want to maintain

- the `LetterInputTileParent`
- and the tiles itself

always nested under the `Canvas` for all cases.

In order to do so you could e.g. find it and do

```
// If possible it is always better to directly reference your objects via the Inspector
// In order to avoid any runtime issues and save some performance
[SerializeField] Canvas _canvas;

private void Awake()
{
    // As a fallback find the canvas on runtime - assuming there is only one anyway
    if(!_canvas) _canvas = FindObjectOfType<Canvas>();

    // You could/should also rather create this one beforehand 
    // and reference this directly via the Inpector
    if(!letterInputTileParent ) 
    {
        letterInputTileParent = new GameObject("LetterInputTileParent");
        // Make sure it is under the Canvas
        letterInputTileParent.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
        letterInputTileParent.SetParent(_canvas.transform, false);
    }

    LetterInputTile = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MLetterTile");
}
```

---

In general I don't fully understand the logic behind your component. But you seem to have it attached to every `LetterSlot`. You do however find **all** objects with the tag `MLetterTile`. Wouldn't they just all run simultaneously?

Also I wouldn't do this using `Update` and a bool flag at all over and over again.

You already have two event messages so why not handle the outcome there **once**.

Also note that your loops `foreach` and then the nested `for` loops are completely redundant and iterating the same items

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
    {
        foreach (GameObject obj in LetterInputTile)
        {
            obj.transform.SetParent(letterInputTileParent.transform);
        }
    }
}

private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile"))
    {
        foreach (GameObject obj in LetterInputTile)
        {
            obj.transform.SetParent(/*probably not null but something else see above*/);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Most probably you don't even want to iterate **at all** - thinking about it, it seems to m that you check for collision with the exact same tag as the objects in your array => You rather want to parent only **this `other`** object you collided with and further probably don't even need to create a new parent object.

I suspect what you rather want to achieve is

- If an object with the tag `MLetterTile` collides with a slot
- Set this slot as the new parent for the object
- If it than exits the slot
- Set it back to its original parent

So I would rather expect something like e.g

```
public class ParentSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Transform, Transform> originalParents = new ();

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(!other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile")) return;
        
        originalParents[other.transform] = other.transform.parent;

        other.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if(!other.gameObject.CompareTag("MLetterTile")) return;
        
        if(!originalParents.Remove(other.transform, out var originalParent)) return;

        other.transform.SetParent(originalParent);
    }
}
```

In the `originalParents` you now find at the same time

- objects currently in this slot (`originalParents.Keys`)
- the original parents to reset them on exiting the slot